# How to set read-only member IsSearchable from StringAttributeMetadata when creating an new attribute using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, dataverse

I try to add a custom attribute to a table in Dataverse. I am successful so far, but I cannot set the base property IsSearchable = true since it is Read-Only (No getter...) in StringAttributeMetadata. I thought I had to feed the other property IsValidForAdvancedFind which has a setter, but when I look at the result in Dynamics user UI it shows false.

```
attribute = new StringAttributeMetadata {
// Set base properties
    SchemaName = "solution name",
    DisplayName = new Label("Attribute name", 1036),
    RequiredLevel = new AttributeRequiredLevelManagedProperty(
        AttributeRequiredLevel.ApplicationRequired),
    Description = new Label("Description", 1036),
    IsAuditEnabled = new BooleanManagedProperty(true),
    IsValidForAdvancedFind = new BooleanManagedProperty(true),
    IsValidForForm = true,
    // IsSearchable = true,   ** cannot do that!
    IsSecured = false
};
CreateAttributeRequest createAttributeRequest = new CreateAttributeRequest
{
    EntityName = "TableName",
    Attribute = attribute
};
createAttributeRequest["SolutionUniqueName"] = "SolutionUniqueName";
// ServiceClient _serviceClient already connected
_serviceClient.Execute(createAttributeRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting the IsValidForAdvancedFind property, the field Searchable is true in the ui. Which is what I was trying to do. You also need to publish after saving in the code.

var request = new PublishXmlRequest { ParameterXml = String.Format("{0}", "LogicalName" };
_serviceClient.Execute(request);